# Overwrite content of Word, Exit the program. How do I recover this?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing an important paper. I need it back in 20 mins or I'm doomed.

Basically I overwrote the content of my word document. Then I closed Word. When I reopen it, I wasn't given the option to recover it. Revision history has no backup...

What can I do to get my original document back?

Thanks.

Comment: D:      ܂܂܂܂܂܂܂܂܂܂܂܂

Comment: I'm so sorry... but... It is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue.

Answer (score 3):

It's a long shot, but there are a couple of things you can try:

1. Disable hiding "hidden" files and check your document's folder for temporary saves (`~WRD????.TMP`).

   These files *should* be deleted on a clean exit, but sometimes they won't.
2. Install [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) and search for deleted files in your document's folder.

   With a little luck, one of the deleted temporary saves will save *you*.

Answer (score 2):

You need a file recovery program to do this sort of thing. However, there are the following issues:

1. They usually cost a lot of money.
2. They take longer than 20 minutes to run.
3. They work best on deleted files, and some of them may have issues completely recovering a file that was simply changed and overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

In *Windows Vista* or *7*, go to the file in My documents, right-click it, press **Properties**, open the **Previous Versions** tab, and wait to see if you have a backup.

Good luck!

Comment: There is none... thanks for helping.. Any way else?

Comment: Which only works if you have the backup source properly configured. It is not on by default.